# Catching arcgisscripting.ExecuteError and error details?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7

I am with ArcGIS 10.1. In my Python script, I need to catch arcgisscripting.ExecuteError and other general Python errors. When a arcgisscripting.ExecuteError is thrown, I also need to retrieve error details.

For example

```
try:
      # UploadServiceDefinition_server would throw a arcgisscripting.ExecuteError error if an error occurs
      arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, 'My Hosted Services', service, 
                                                 '', 'FROM_SERVICE_DEFINITION', 'EXISTING', 
                                                 'STARTED', 'OVERRIDE_DEFINITION', 'SHARE_ONLINE', 
                                                 'PUBLIC', 'SHARE_ORGANIZATION', '')

except arcgisscripting.ExecuteError:

except:
  general errors
finally:
  do other stuff
```

Comment: Have you seen https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/12/01/tips-and-tricks-error-handling-in-python-script-tools/?

Comment: This link no longer works, does this blog post exist anywhere else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect what you actually want to catch is an [`arcpy.ExecuteError`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-classes/executeerror.htm) (or have you imported `arcgisscripting` somewhere in your code?)

```
except arcpy.ExecuteError:
    print arcpy.GetMessages()
    # Handle the code somehow
except Exception:
    e = sys.exc_info()[1]
    print(e.args[0])
    arcpy.AddError(e.args[0])
finally:
  do other stuff
```

See also [Error handling with Python](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python/error-handling-with-python.htm)